# Deleting/referencing a tag with an invalid character

Tags: git, github

Somehow, somebody managed to create a tag with a question-mark in its name.  Now, every time I fetch, it seems to think I don't have the tag and announces it in the output:

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:myrepo
 * [new tag]         2011-01-28-rc2? -> 2011-01-28-rc2?
From github.com:myrepo
 * [new tag]         2011-01-28-rc2? -> 2011-01-28-rc2?
```

That's not a copy-paste error - it gets output twice.

I'm sure this is harmless, but it's driving me crazy.  I've tried the obvious command to delete the tag:

```
$ git push origin :refs/tags/2011-01-28-rc2?
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :refs/tags/2011-01-28-rc2?
```

Is there some escape sequence I need to use, or am I misunderstanding what I'm seeing here?

If it's relevant, this is on github.

Comment: Can you give the github url of this repo? It is likely that the ? is a character which your shell can't print. Also when you have this tag already in your local repo you can use the shell autocoletion to spell the tag name with `.git/refs/tags/2011-01-28-rc2<tab>`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.  It's a private repo..

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already, try using a unicode-capable shell such as urxvt.  Then if git fetch origin still shows a question mark, copy-paste it back into your terminal when you try to delete the tag.  This way you can delete a tag with a character that you don't have a font glyph for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, although I do not know if my tag had invalid character in it. Try this:

```
git push origin --delete 2011-01-28-rc2?
```